# Does IntelliJ Idea remember my history?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I would like to ask whether IntelliJ IDEA remember my historical steps in some files or not.

To be clear, I would like to see a history of editing of a project that has been sent to me by e-mail. Is it possible somehow?

Thank you

Marek

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Intellij keeps a history. By default this is held in the project's .idea folder, so unless you've been sent that along with the project, which is unlikely, then you won't have access to it. You can view local-history, or recent-changes, on a per file basis.

Here's the intellij documentation for the [recent changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-recent-changes.html) feature, and here is the [local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html).